# JSON post returning null when passed from view to controller

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json, http-post

vm.Name returns null when it's passed from view to controller but when I call for the data in view, it shows up fine.

```
$scope.afterSelectedIngredient = function (selected) {
            if (selected) {
                $scope.selectedIngredient = selected.originalObject;
                $scope.newIngs = [];
                var ing = {};
                ing.Name = $scope.selectedIngredient;
                $scope.newIngs.push(ing);
                console.log($scope.newIngs)
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/Ingredients/createIngredient',
                    data: $scope.newIngs
                }).then(function (response) {
                    console.log("ingredient exist: "+response.data)
                }, function () { alert('Error'); });
            }
        }
```

**IngredientsController**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult createIngredient(Ingredient vm)
    {
        Ingredient ingredient = new Ingredient();
        ingredient.Name = vm.Name;
        bool IngredientExists = db.Ingredients.Any(ing => ing.Name==vm.Name);
        if (IngredientExists)
        {
            return Json(IngredientExists);
        }
        else
        {
            db.Ingredients.Add(ingredient);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return Json(IngredientExists);
    }
```

I tried the following but vm still returned null

- Changing "ActionResult" to "JsonResult"
- Changing "Ingredient" to "string[]"
- Wrapping the data in JSON.stringify()
- I removed the required in Name in the Ingredient model

I also tried other things but in the end it still returns null...

Comment: The controller method expects an object and not a collection. You should pass `ing` object in  `$http data` and not `$scope.newIngs`.

Comment: It worked! thanks @Sajal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed what @Sajal said, I removed the "$scope.newIngs.push(ing);" and then changed the data "$scope.newIngs" to "ing" and now it works!

```
$scope.afterSelectedIngredient = function (selected) {
            if (selected) {
                $scope.selectedIngredient = selected.originalObject;
                $scope.newIngs = [];
                var ing = {};
                ing.Name = $scope.selectedIngredient;
                console.log($scope.newIngs)
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/Ingredients/createIngredient',
                    data: ing
                }).then(function (response) {
                    console.log("ingredient exist: "+response.data)
                }, function () { alert('Error'); });
            }
        }
```